# Turn off SmartScreen Filter?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I got all of a sudden the IE SmartScreen Filter warning on several sites. I checked them, they are fine. No viruses or malware. My users complain about this a lot. How can I get rid of this warning?

I don't mean in a browser, but on the sites that are affected.